# Not sure if programmer or ATMega is burned

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, power, motor

some time ago i tried doing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMz2DYpos8w) with my original arduino uno r3. I guess i had to plug the power cables in wrong order(i think it's called reversing polarity)  because my arduino stoped working. It turns on (the power diode is on) but i cannot upload any sketch on it. I'm thinking about changing the ATMega chip but, before i do that i want to be certain that it's the chip issue ,not the programmer. I have another arduino uno, and i heard that i can upload sketch with it to another uno. So my idea is, if i do this i will be able to say whether it's the programmer or the chip issue. The only problem is that i don't know how to do this and i wasn't able to find any reasonable tutorials online. Please tell me what to do.
Many Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Does the uno show up in the Device Manager? You could also have burned the ATMega16u2 that does the usb-to-serial.

Comment: I think it does, i will check it when i'm back home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino IDE ships with a built in `ArduinoISP` sketch, and there is a very detailed [tutorial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) with wiring diagrams etc on the Arduino site.

Comment: But doesn't it alow me only to burn a bootloader ? I would like to upload a simplest sketch (for example Blink) to check whether does the chip work.

Comment: No, you can program anything you want with ISP. When you use a boot loader, you can only program the non-bootloader section, but the converse is not true.